# Is it currently impossible to publish UWP apps to Store when using F#?

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store

I have a Xamarin.Forms app on Android, iOS, and UWP that's already published to all relevant app stores. It's written in C#, but a new feature was recently implemented partly in F#. This means I can't use .NET Native compilation on my UWP project. I turned off .NET Native compilation, but discovered that I now can't publish updates to Windows Store any longer.

Is there any way around this, or is it simply impossible for the time being to publish Xamarin.Forms apps using F# to the Windows Store? I know there's something called [Desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root), but I have no idea if this is usable in this context.

If it's currently impossible to publish XF apps using F# to Windows Store, is there any estimate on when this will be possible?

(cross-posted on the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104131/is-it-currently-impossible-to-publish-uwp-apps-to-store-when-using-f/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 1/23/2019

It is possible to use .net native with F# UWP but, it is not officially supported.

https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/6055

> We can confirm that .Net Native compilation works now on Store
> compilation machines, and we have released our beta F# app on the
> store (link).

https://www.reddit.com/r/fsharp/comments/acj7dn/f_winrtuwp_apps_on_net_native_are_now_releasable/?utm_source=reddit-android

Screencap for posterity (should the link change)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

At this time [Sep 29 '17] it appears that .NET Native, the technology used to pre-compile **UWP** apps, as I understand it, still does not support F#.

Here's the GH issue on this, with a linked [work-around](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1096#issuecomment-301326696) for publishing Win32 and .NET apps--but I suspect if you want a UWP app, no such luck: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1096